# Is there an android music player that can play from dropbox?

Tags: music, android, dropbox

I tend to keep my current favorite music in Dropbox so that I can listen to it at home and work.  My android phone has can also play music from Dropbox but to do so, you have to select each song individually.

Does anyone know of an android music player that will play from Dropbox an album at a time?

Comment: See: [How do I play mp3s from my Dropbox?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9449/how-do-i-play-mp3s-from-my-dropbox) and possibly similar questions on [android.SE]

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried or Tested it but I guess this will be perfect for you:

[DropNPlay Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.doublecore.musicdropnplaylite)

OR try

[CloudAround](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cloudaround)

This should be the answer to your question.